# Special Characters Menu in Wagtail Editor

Tags: javascript, django, content-management-system, special-characters, wagtail

I am trying to add a menu of special characters in the wagtail editor so that users can add a menu of selected special characters to the content. What is the best way to do this? I can't find any plugins on this page either: https://wagtail.io/packages/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the official documentation on [how to extend the Draftail editor](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/extending_draftail.html). I would love to have these special characters as a standard feature, though! Following the documentation it is possible to add buttons for entities.